# snmpget: not found, but I do have the snmpget binary

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, snmp, net-snmp

I compiled net-snmp and copy installation package to ARM based linux.
Because the file system is small so I deleted all the commands binaries except snmpd and snmpget.

Then on the ARM board when I tried to do "snmpget" I got error "not found".
but I do have the snmpget binary. (net-snmp provides all these)

My question is, looks like I am not going to do a manual install using something like "yum" or "rpm". I need to use the net-snmp installation package.
the "snmpget" binary is on the board. 
What am I missing now?
Thank you all !!

Comment: Probably a dynamic library. Did you build against the actual target filesystem, or some cross-compiler's pre-packaged sysroot?

Comment: thanks I have solved that, I am stupid , I should use ./snmpget before setting EXPORT PATH